# Invalid schema element named "JobeetCategories" at path "JobeetAffiliate"

Tags: symfony-1.4, jobeet

I have followd this tutorial[Joobeet 1.4 Day 3](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03)

```
<code> JobeetCategory:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }

JobeetJob:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer, notnull: true }
    type:         { type: string(255) }
    company:      { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    logo:         { type: string(255) }
    url:          { type: string(255) }
    position:     { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    location:     { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    description:  { type: string(4000), notnull: true }
    how_to_apply: { type: string(4000), notnull: true }
    token:        { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
    is_public:    { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 1 }
    is_activated: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 0 }
    email:        { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    expires_at:   { type: timestamp, notnull: true }
  relations:
    JobeetCategory: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: category_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: JobeetJobs }

JobeetAffiliate:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    url:       { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    email:     { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
    token:     { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    is_active: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 0 }
  relations:
    JobeetCategories:
      class: JobeetCategory
      refClass: JobeetCategoryAffiliate
      local: affiliate_id
      foreign: category_id
      foreignAlias: JobeetAffiliates

JobeetCategoryAffiliate:
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer, primary: true }
    affiliate_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
  relations:
    JobeetCategory:  { onDelete: CASCADE, local: category_id, foreign: id }
    JobeetAffiliate: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: affiliate_id, foreign: id } </code>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working in me.
1. Check schema.yml for syntax error.
2. 
2.1 Back Up your project.
2.2 (I think this is help you). Go to the **lib/model/doctrine/base** - and delete all files. 
Make :

```
$ php symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load --no-confirmation
```

UPD : Delete all files also in : **lib/form/doctrine/base**, **lib/filter/doctrine/base**